# Google Home won't respond, waits 30s to a minute and then says "something went wrong" or "there was a glitch"

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I had a power surge (could have been a 2-second outage but I don't know) and ever since none of my Google homes have been able to respond to any command. The Assistant just keeps listening (the white dots pulse to ambient noise, even the quieted music gets picked up) and after a while it spits out the same error as always "something went wrong, try again in a few seconds".

- I  have a Google Home, a GH Mini and a JBL Link 10.
- My network has a Philips Hue hub plugged into my Google WiFi, and the GWiFi plugged into my AP.
- Gwifi reports that both the mesh and my connection are flawless, I've rebooted Gwifi.
- Have performed FDR on GHmini to no avail, after a new setup the same problems occur.
- Basically expensive paperweights at this point unless casting from a davice directly to them, the assistant is absent.

Additionally, I am still able to cast music from Spotify on the GH, GHmini and JBLink, and my Chromecast Ultra isn't having any problems at all.

Comment: Since you didn't specifically state it: have you powered down and back up the Google Home device? I use Amazon Echo devices myself, and they seem to loose there mind when the power glitches. I have to unplug them and power them back up and they seem to resync with the mothership and start working correctly after that.

Comment: Yes I had rebooted in both software and via the power cable. my "solution" was to switch my ISP to one that didn't hold a data cap over it's customers. Protip: don't use Telus if you live in Canada, they throttle you down to GSM-level speed if you break their data cap.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following in this order, testing after each one:

1. Power the device off, wait a few minutes, power it back on (I know you said you already did this, but it is worth another shot).
2. Power cycle your modem/router
3. [Hard reset the device](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7073477?hl=en)